# Bound ListView displaying wrong items

Tags: caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1

I have a simple ListView bound to a BindableCollection (async ObservableCollection). I am populating the BindableCollection in an async method. After a refresh, the collection contains about 130 unique items. However, the ListView displays many of the items repeatedly. Checking the actual contents of the collection, I can see they are definitely unique. The contents are something like the following

- mazzy star
- neil young
- the babies
- haunted leather
- alice boman
- compilations
- richard swift
- rolling stones
- fleetwood mac
- future islands
- lily & madeleine
- darlenya
- darlenya (different from last)
- father john misty
- eels
- sharon van etten
- feeding people
- helado negro
- **neil young** *first repeat*
- **the babies**
- **haunted leather**
- **alice boman**
- **compilations**
- **richard swift**
- **rolling stones**
- **fleetwood mac**
- **future islands**
- **lily & madeleine**
- **darlenya**
- **darlenya (different from last)**
- **father john misty**
- **eels**
- **sharon van etten**
- **feeding people**
- **helado negro**
- **neil young** *second repeat*
- **the babies**
- **...**
- **eels**

The ViewModel

```
    private readonly BindableCollection<Track> _tracks = new BindableCollection<Track>();
    private readonly ITrackFeedService _feedService;

    public ICollection<Track> Tracks
    {
        get { return _tracks; }
    }

    public async void UpdateTracksAsync()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        _tracks.Clear();
        var tracks = await _feedService.LoadAsync();
        _tracks.AddRange(tracks);

        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

The View (bound through caliburn.micro convention)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="Tracks" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TrackDataTemplate}"
              Grid.Row="1">
    </ListView>
</Grid>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TrackDataTemplate">
        <Grid cm:Bind.Model="{Binding}" Margin="0 0 0 5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Name="Artwork" Height="100" Width="100"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Name="Title" Style="{StaticResource TrackTextStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Name="Artist" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource TrackTextStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Name="Album" Grid.Row="2" />
                <TextBlock Name="ReleaseYear" Grid.Row="3" />
                <TextBlock Name="Label" Grid.Row="4" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Feed Service

```
    public Task<IEnumerable<Track>> LoadAsync()
    {
        var scraper = new TrackWebScraper(URL);
        return scraper.Scrape();
    }
```

I've tried replacing BindableCollection with the standard ObservableCollection with the same result. I'm certain my service is returning a collection of unique items. I can see the ListView clearing when the collection is cleared before grabbing the new items. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 _tracks = null;

  var tracks = await _feedService.LoadAsync();
  _tracks = tracks;
```

Comment: Causes the list to be empty.

Comment: If you're unsure about it being the solution, post it as a comment. If it turns out the be the right thing, post it as an answer, instead of posting "Try this" answers. Currently, it's auto-flagged as low quality.